# From String Array want remove Single quote

Tags: javascript, json

I have this String:

```
'[{"name":"$1 Silver Membership Trial - Silver-Membership-3-Month","price":"279.88", "quantity":1}]'
```

And I would like to format it as either:

```
[{
  "name": "$1 Silver Membership Trial - Silver-Membership-3-Month",
  "price": "279.88",
  "quantity": 1
}]
```

or

```
[{
  'name': '$1 Silver Membership Trial - Silver-Membership-3-Month',
  'price': '279.88',
  'quantity': 1
}]
```

Comment: use `JSON.parse(str)`.

Answer (score 1):

That's a JSON string, so parse it to get the object

```js
let str = '[{"name":"$1 Silver Membership Trial - Silver-Membership-3-Month","price":"279.88", "quantity":1}]';

console.log(JSON.parse(str) )
```